# Abort sorting in DataGridView when row has been edited

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have DataGridView with 2 columns. SortMode of first is set to Automatic.

In this grid is a lot rows, and when I change value in the row, for example from xyz to abc I still in position where this row WAS. Edited row jumps to top.

I want to abort this automatic sorting and I want call sorting by left click on column. Be

I found some solution (code below + I set SortMode  to Programmatically), but my row still jumping :/ Has anyone solution to tackle with this issue?

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn newColumn =
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

        SortOrder direction;
        if (dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn,
            ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            direction = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn,
            ListSortDirection.Descending);
            direction = SortOrder.Descending;
        }

        newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = direction;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just disable the sorting when capturing the Edit Event of your DataGridView ?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender,
DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
      column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Then you could just restore the Sorting by reverting this behavior (by restoring it again in the RightClick event of your column or whatever Context menu Item or other)

Comment: This solution doesn't work. At start I set for every column not sortable. Now in dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick at start I added: newColumn.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic; . And of cource I've added your event , and still the same.